# How to filter keys in MapType in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given a DataFrame as below is it possible to filter out some keys of the Column *collection* (MapType(StringType, StringType, True)) in PySpark while keeping the schema intact?

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- collection: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You should create `udf` responsible for filtering keys from map and use it with `withColumn` transformation to filter keys from `collection` field.

Below example implementation in Scala:

```
// Start from implementing method in Scala responsible for filtering keys from Map
def filterKeys(collection: Map[String, String], keys: Iterable[String]): Map[String, String] =
    collection.filter{case (k,_) => !keys.exists(_ == k)}

// Create Spark UDF based on above function
val filterKeysUdf = udf((collection: Map[String, String], keys: Iterable[String]) => filterKeys(collection, keys))

// Use above udf to filter keys
val newDf = df.withColumn("collection", filterKeysUdf(df("collection"), lit(Array("k1"))))
```

Implementation in Python:

```
# Start from implementing method in Python responsible for filtering keys from dict
def filterKeys(collection, keys):
    return {k:collection[k] for k in collection if k not in keys}

# Create Spark UDF based on above function
filterKeysUdf = udf(filterKeys, MapType(StringType(), StringType()))

# Create array literal based on Python list
keywords_lit = array(*[lit(k) for k in ["k1","k2"]])

# Use above udf to filter keys
newDf = df.withColumn("collection", filterKeysUdf(df.collection, keywords_lit))
```

Comment: In python tricky part is getting a MapType as an output of the udf

Comment: Hi @yauheni_selivonchyk, I've added implementation in Python.

Answer (score 3):

In version 3.1 you can do this with map_filter:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn("filtered_map", f.map_filter("map_col", lambda _, v: v is not None))
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add onto what Piotr Kalański said in case you were looking to filter null values.

```
def filterValue(collection):
  return {k:collection[k] for k in collection if collection[k]}

filterValuesUdf = F.udf(filterValue, MapType(StringType(), StringType()))

newDf = source_map_df.withColumn("collection", filterValuesUdf(source_map_df.f))
```