# Spark : remove keys of a map column

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset `ds` containing a map column `userInfo` that has 3 keys :

```
{"name":"Tom", "age":"52", "phone":"45124"}
```

Now I want in my new dataset `dsNew` also have this map column (e.g. `dsNew = ds.withColumn(...)`), but removes the key "phone". What is the best way performance-wise to do this ?

Note that this is only a simplified example, in reality this map column has many key-value pairs and I want to remove a subset of it.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703614/extract-or-filter-maptype-of-spark-dataframe  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706176/how-to-filter-keys-in-maptype-in-pyspark

Answer (score 2):

In addition to my linked answers which uses UDF, if your Spark version >= 3.0, you can also use [`map_filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_filter):

```
dsNew = ds.withColumn("userInfo", expr("map_filter(userInfo, (k, v) -> k != 'phone')"))
```

If you have a number of keys to remove, you can use `not in`:

```
dsNew = ds.withColumn("userInfo", expr("map_filter(userInfo, (k, v) -> k not in ('phone', 'phone2'))"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 3 keys it's simple to create new map by getting the 2 keys you want to keep :

```
val dsNew = ds.withColumn(
  "userInfo",
  map(lit("name"), $"userInfo"("name"), lit("age"), $"userInfo"("age"))
)

dsNew.show
//+------------------------+
//|userInfo                |
//+------------------------+
//|[name -> Tom, age -> 52]|
//+------------------------+
```

---

Map filtering is only available since version 3 of spark as pointed in the other answer. In spark 2.4, you can get the keys and filter them using array functions then create new map with the filtered keys using `map_from_arrays` function:

```
val dsNew = ds.withColumn(
    "filtered_keys",
    expr("filter(map_keys(userInfo), x -> x <> 'phone')")
  ).withColumn(
    "userInfo",
    map_from_arrays(
      $"filtered_keys",
      expr("transform(filtered_keys, x -> userInfo[x])")
    )
  ).drop("filtered_keys")
```